# MacBook Air 2017 Photos App Not Detecting Some Photos From iPad 5

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, photos.app

I am trying to import videos from my iPad 5 (running iOS 12.0.1) to my 2017 MacBook Air (MacBookAir7,2 running macOS High Sierra 10.13.5) through the Photos app and half of my iPad's photos aren't showing up...

What I've already tried:

- Using another computer
- Using another cable
- Using another USB Port on the MacBook
- Restarting macOS
- Resetting Location And Privacy on the iPad (so it asks if i wanna
  trust the mac again)

Hope someone can find the answer

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try using Image Capture.app on your Mac. See if it shows you all the photos and videos. You can also simply drag and drop photos and videos from Image Capture.app to desired directory directly.

Comment: @NimeshNeema That just shows pictures, I am trying to import videos

Comment: Image Capture.app is capable of importing videos captured from Camera app in iOS too. Can you see the videos in the Photos app on your iPad?

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes I can, its just the mac that can't detect the videos